# Getting the first element and second element from a specific tag in simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have two div tags with the same class name one after the other:-

**HTML:**

```
<div class='random'>
    <div class="name">
        <h1>Title 1</h1>
        <p>Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="name">
        <h1>Title 2</h1>
        <p>Other Description</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='random'>
    <div class="name">
        <h1>Title 2-1</h1>
        <p>Description2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="name">
        <h1>Title 2-2</h1>
        <p>Other Description2</p>
    </div>
</div>
.....
.....
```

Now I want to get both descriptions seperately:

> Output 1 desired:-
>   Description
>
> Output 2 desired:-
>   Other Description
>
> But My output: 
>   Description 
>   Other Description

**Code:**

```
foreach($html->find('div.name p') as $value)
{
    echo $value->innertext;
}
```

Is there any way such that we can specify only the first class or second class to be printed?

Comment: You can use ->find('selector', $my_desired_number)

Comment: Actually i dont get what is the problem ... your desired output is the same as current output

Comment: will that work ?? Will try it

Comment: @kirugan i want to get seperately both the <p>

Comment: If you mean ->find method yes it works, i`m using it right now

Comment: Yes find works but hw to specify the number ?? like the only the 1st class etc or 2nd class

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26684/discussion-between-kirugan-and-pavan-k)

Answer (score 4):

First class(es):

```
$html->find('div.name[1] p')
```

Second class(es):

```
$html->find('div.name[2] p')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Find (N)th anchor, returns element object or null if not found (zero based)
$ret = $html->find('a', 0);

// Find lastest anchor, returns element object or null if not found (zero based)
$ret = $html->find('a', -1);
```

Try this. It helps!

Comment: Or try this.
// If you are not so familiar with HTML DOM, check this link  to learn more... 

// Example
echo $html->find("#div1", 0)->children(1)->children(1)->children(2)->id;
// or 
echo $html->getElementById("div1")->childNodes(1)->childNodes(1)->childNodes(2)->getAttribute('id');

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)

```
mixed find ( string $selector [, int $index] )  Find children by the CSS selector. Returns the Nth element object if index is set, otherwise, return an array of object.
```

Don't use a loop, instead do something like this:

```
echo "Output 1 desired:-<BR>";
echo $html->find('div.name p', 0) . "<BR>";
echo "Output 1 desired:-<BR>";
echo $html->find('div.name p', 1);
```

Comment: I am getting warning Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: try removing the ->innertext part

Comment: Nw i am getting:-  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: i said not to use a foreach... get rid of what you have, and paste my code there instead

Comment: Then you need to fix your question to show exactly what you're doing

Comment: It's very unclear what you're actually asking. How is what you currently have, not exactly what you're saying you want?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26685/discussion-between-pavan-k-and-elefantphace)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$count = count($html->find('div.name p'));


 for($index=0; $index<$count; $index++)
{
$text = getElementByIndex($html, $index);
echo "output $index : $text";
}

function getElementByIndex($html,$index)
{
return $html->find('div.name p', $index);
}
```

Hope it helps you ..

Comment: any error .. ? I have tried it and it works like charm .try turing on error reporting

Comment: It is telling $html is unsused in its scope

Comment: @PavanK Please tell me is it giving any php error ... on server

Comment: do you have error reporting on ini_set('display_errors', '1')

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code

```
echo  $htmlEN->find('.name h1', 0)->innertext;
echo  $htmlEN->find('.name p', 0)->innertext;
```

and

```
echo  $htmlEN->find('.name h1', 1)->innertext;
echo  $htmlEN->find('.name p', 1)->innertext;
```

......